# Adding additional user pool groups using amplify auth update?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

How do I add an additional group to Cognito user pool groups?

`amplify auth update` only gives an option to delete existing groups.

```
Using service: Cognito, provided by: awscloudformation
 What do you want to do? Create or update Cognito user pool groups
? Select any user pool groups you want to delete: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
 ◯ admin
❯◯ editors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without selecting any of them just press Enter

```
Using service: Cognito, provided by: awscloudformation
 What do you want to do? Create or update Cognito user pool groups
? Select any user pool groups you want to delete: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
 ◯ admin
❯◯ editors
```

The next question would be

```
? Do you want to add another User Pool Group
```

Comment: That was it. It would've been nice to have additional `<enter> to create new`